# Keying an (unordered_)map using a multimap iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, multimap

I'm building a software where one class is responsible to log info sources and commands (both are grouped as requests), where all requests are inserted inside a multimap, wherein the multimap is keyed by the request name, and each element points to request structure that holds management information and callback function pointer, insighted from [this software](https://github.com/philbowles/h4plugins/blob/master/src/H4P_SerialCmd.cpp#L126).

The callbacks are executed to issue a command, or to get an info, and everything is ok until here.

To enable subscription-based information delivery, I've introduced a new map keyed by the request iterator, so where calling `subscribe("infoID")` the software looks for the exact match request and return its iterator.

Because these iterators are unique per request, I've found it useful to key the subscriptions map using it. Where the key points to info subscriber's callback-functions.

The error is:

> error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const
> std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const
> std::__cxx11::basic_string, request>, false, true>' and 'const
> std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const
> std::__cxx11::basic_string, request>, false, true>')
> { return __x < __y; }

Followed by 15 compiling notes 'template argument deduction/substitution failed':

> 'const std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const
> std::__cxx11::basic_string, request>, false, true>' is not
> derived from 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>'
> { return __x < __y; }
> each one with a unique source: `const std::pair<_T1, _T2>`, `const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>` (stl_function.h), `const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>` (stl_iterator.h), ... etc.

Full error [here](https://pastebin.com/vtK7fq0M).

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct request
{
    string f1;
};

using   SYS_REQMAP          =unordered_multimap<string, request, hash<string>>;
using   SYS_REQMAP_I        =SYS_REQMAP::iterator;

using SYS_INFOSUB_CBF   = function<void(string, string)>;
using SYS_INFOSUB_CBFS  = vector<SYS_INFOSUB_CBF>;

using SYS_REQINF_SUBS   = map<SYS_REQMAP_I, SYS_INFOSUB_CBFS>;

void cbf(const string& a, const string& b){}
int main()
{
    SYS_REQINF_SUBS infoSubr;
    SYS_REQMAP vm{{"cmd1", {"foo"}},
                {"cmd2", {"bar"}}};

    for (SYS_REQMAP_I it = vm.begin(); it != vm.end(); it++)
    {
        infoSubr[it].push_back(cbf);    // Compile error
    }
}

void compilesOK()
{
    using SYS_REQINF_SUBS_1 = std::map<int, SYS_INFOSUB_CBFS>;
    SYS_REQINF_SUBS_1 subs1;
    subs1[1].push_back(cbf);    // Compiles OK
}
```

And here's [OnlineGDB link to compile and observe output](https://onlinegdb.com/0tYFaEWUM).

Comment: You'll need to provide a custom comparator for your map to compare 2 iterators

Comment: Maybe related: How do you expect this `printf("%lu\n", it);` to work out, `it` being an `unordered_multimap<string, request, hash<string>>::iterator` ...

Comment: Hi @Kevin, Tried out solutions to make custom compare, but 'no operator "<" matches these operands', casting doesn't work although.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, My purpose was to prove it has a unique address at memory, and it works.

Comment: @HamzaHajeir _"it works"_ - is not guaranteed. You were "lucky" if the conversion from an  `unordered_multimap<string, request, hash<string>>::iterator` to a `long unsigned` worked without causing all sorts of UB.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Correct, It wont be included in any production code.

Comment: @HamzaHajeir Why include it in _any_ code?

Comment: @TedLyngmo To validate an idea of uniqueness of it, now it's removed. Can you add something to solve the error?

Comment: @HamzaHajeir Sure: Do not code at random. If you are sure what every thing you write does, it will also be much more likely that your compiler creates a program displaying your intent.

Comment: At this case, I've designed the structure of the software upfront and everything in development goes seemless to a good extent, the issue is shorted to an assumpion that I made with the iterator being the key in the design process. And it's now seems solved (see [link](https://cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/283947/)). I might enhance the software design at this process too by ideas discussed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterator requires a custom comparison function _Compare:

```cpp
struct Compare_REQMAP_I
{
    bool operator()(const SYS_REQMAP_I& lhs, const SYS_REQMAP_I& rhs) const {
        return &lhs < &rhs;
    }
};

using SYS_REQINF_SUBS   = std::map<SYS_REQMAP_I, SYS_INFOSUB_CBFS, Compare_REQMAP_I>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The key part of the error is:

```
stl_map.h:481:32:   required from 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, ....>
[with _Key = std::__detail::_Node_iterator ....
...
stl_function.h:386:20: error: no match for 'operator<'
```

`std::map` (aka ordered map) keys are required to be comparable (`operator<`), but map iterators are not comparable, and thus cannot be used in an ordered map.

The simpliest solutions is to use some other type.

Other solutions are to provide the map with a comparitor (`_Compare`), to tell it how to compare iterators, or switch to a `unordered_map` and provide a hasher to tell it how to hash iterators.

Comment: Thanks @Mooing,  I'd appreciate if you can point out how can I go for the 'other' solutions.

Comment: Those are not small concepts, you need a good C++ book that teaches how to use `map` and `unodered_map`

Comment: Thank you, I'll go in deep at those concepts at some point in the future. Now the issue seems to be solved..
I guess it starts in data structures and algorithms at first. c++ is a tool, so that comes second.